# Estimating treatment effect on a variable measured on a Likert scale at two points in time: How?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

How to compare the effect of receiving treatment on a dependent variable measured using a Likert scale (0-7), using such data:

```
#   Group       Rating at baseline  Rating at endline
1   Treatment           2                  5
2   Treatment           3                  3
3   Control             4                  7
4   Control             5                  9
```

Comment: Can treatment move the baseline rating? Or does treatment happen between baseline and endline surveys?

Comment: Are you able to match an individual's baseline response to their endline response ?  That is, in your table is # 1 an individual with 2 at baseline and 5 at endline ?

Comment: @dimitriy: Hello! Treatment happens between baseline and endline surveys.

Comment: @Sal Magniafico Yes, baseline and endline responses in each row belong to the same individual.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the preferred approach would be to use ordinal regression.  This is analogous to using a general linear model, akin to anova, except for an ordinal dependent variable.

However, assuming you have several individuals in your sample, you will want to account for the repeated measures --- or paired --- nature of the data.  (That is, the same individual has a baseline and an endline value.)  This can be accomplished by using a mixed effects model.

Mixed effects ordinal regression should be relatively easy in good, modern software packages.  R has an *ordinal* package, which makes quick work of the problem, and has options for post-hoc analysis.

So your model is perhaps `Y ~ Group + Time + (1|Individual)`